# While loop showing only one result

Tags: php, while-loop

I want to show string outside while loop, but it only shows one result.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myarr = array();
}
echo $myarr;
```

This shows only one result but I need all the results outside the while loop.
Could you please help me how is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you want the whole row returned from the query or just a single field.

If its the whole row then try

```
$myarr = array(); // initialize
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myarr[] = $row;
}
print_r($myarr);
```

This will give you an array containing `n` row arrays.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :**

You are just assigning the result one after again

```
$myarr = array();
```

Here, It means you're assigning the `array()` again and again, which replaces the old value

**Solution / What You should do**

**1. You can assign it to an Array  (Good Approach)**

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myarr[] = $row['yourdbitem'];  // or $row if you want whole row
}
print_r($myarr);
```

**2. You can concat in each iteration (Bad Approach)**

```
$somevariable = '';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$somevariable .= $row['yourdbitem'];  // or $row if you want whole row
}
echo $somevariable
```

**Note :**

I have given good and bad approach to updating what you should do and what you should not do :)